# How can I filter the information excluding some of the values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have the following tables:

```
create table Person (

    id_person int,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id_person)
);

create table Journey (

    id_journey int,
    year int,
    country varchar(255),
    primary key (id_journey),
);

create table Person_Journey (

    id_journey int references Journey (id_journey),
    id_person int references Person (id_person),
    primary key (id_journey, id_travel)
);
```

Imagine the data inserted into this tables are:

Table Person

```
   id_person                name
-----------------------------------------------
      1                     Jake
      2                     Kevin 
      3                     Denis
```

Table Journey (and table Person_Journey):

```
   id_person         id_travel          country
---------------------------------------------------
      1                 1               France
      1                 2               Germany
      1                 3               Portugal
      2                 4               UK
      2                 5               Germany
      2                 6               UK
      3                 7               UK
      3                 8               Portugal
      3                 9               Germany
```

As the previous example shows, person with `id_person = 1` has travelled to `Portugal`, `Germany` and `France`. Person with `id_person = 2` has travelled to the `UK` two times and to `Germany`. Finally, person with `id_person = 3` has travelled to `UK`, `Germany` and `Portugal`.

I have to execute a `SELECT` on where I want to show the `id_person` and it's respective `name` from ONLY the persons that has travelled to the `UK` AND `Germany`.

So the output I want to get is:

```
    id_person      name
------------------------------
       2           Kevin
```

I have tried executing this with no success:

```
select P.* from Person as P, Journey as J, Person_Journey as PJ
where P.id_person = PJ.id_person and J.id_journey = PJ.id_journey
and J.country in ("UK", "Germany")
group by (P.id_person)
having count(J.country) = 2;
```

How can I do this? I'm using MySQL

Comment: Is your university in 1991?

Comment: Explicit `JOIN` is the current 25+ year ANSI-1992 SQL standard that long replaced implicit joins as you do in `WHERE`. Please reach out to instructor and/or program to adjust curriculum as not teaching explicit join is a disservice to students of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Person.* FROM Person_Journey
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id_journey FROM Journey
    WHERE 
    country in('Germany', 'UK')
    GROUP BY id_journey
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT country) = 2
) t
ON Person_Journey.id_journey = t.id_journey
INNER JOIN Person ON Person.id_person = Person_Journey.id_person
```

Well, one solution without joins could be with `IN`'s:

```
SELECT * FROM Person
    WHERE id_person IN (
    SELECT id_person FROM Person_Journey
    WHERE id_journey IN(
        SELECT id_journey FROM Journey
        WHERE 
        country in('Germany', 'UK')
        GROUP BY id_journey
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT country) = 2
    )
)
```

Though, say in university, that joins are still better, than this ))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please, how would this be without using joins? It might be a weird question, I know.

Comment: haven't studied joins yet at university and we are not allowed to use them

Comment: Appreciate it and will say it at university. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `EXISTS`:

**Pseudo code**: 
Select person names where their ID appear in a row "Germany" and in a row "UK" of the Journey table.

Which would translate to:

```
SELECT p.name FROM Person p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Journey j
    WHERE country='UK' 
    AND p.id_person = j.id_person
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Journey j
    WHERE country='Germany' 
    AND p.id_person = j.id_person
)
```